# How do i add rounded borders to my b-table using only CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

I want to have my b-table have rounded borders
I've tried multiple different solutions I found online but it still hasn't worked out for me

For reference, this is what I want my table to look like in terms of borders:-
[image]

And this is my current table:-
[image]

for my CSS I've used the following:-

```
.content-table {
border-collapse: separate;
margin: 25px 0;
font-size: 0.9em;
min-width: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 2px solid #5B5B5B;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #5B5B5B;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

However, as my current table image show, this means my rows do not have their top or bottom headers
I have also tried using `border-collapse: collapsed` without the `border-spacing 0` but then I will get a result like this:-
[image]

However, this is also an issue whereby the border is extending over in all the corners
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: but your "current table" does have rounded corner. Do you want a line between each row as well?

Answer (score 0):

Adding rounded border to a table is little bit tricky,

```
table { position:relative;max-width:600px }

table::after {
  content: " ";
  inset: 0;
  border: solid #000 1px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kukrati/pen/PoKaYPx)